# How to increase array element in a loop in Pine Script?

Tags: arrays, loops, pine-script

I'm trying to count a number of bars witch are closed in a given range and use an array for storing this info. Here is a code example:

```
ar = array.new_float(1000, 0)

var int myInc = 0 

var tess = 0
myInc := 0

while myInc <= 4
    if close < 41000 and close > 39000
        tess := tess + 1
        array.set(ar, 400, array.get(ar, 400)+1)
    myInc += 1
```

The data in "tess" variable is stored correctly, but in array I receive zero value. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you want to use `myInc` in your `array.x()` calls to increment the index? And why does your index start from 400?

Comment: Don't completely understand what do you mean by using array.x() calls, could you please provide a short example? 400 is only for example, I'm trying to use array to define support/resistance levels, so number of array element multiplied by some coefficient will define a level.

Comment: I meant, don't you want something like  `array.set(ar, 400+myInc , array.get(ar, 400+myInc )+1)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm trying to use array index as second dimension in matrix, where one dimension is a count of bars touching some level and second (array index) is a price level. It would be easy if pine script allow to create normal 2 dimensional matrices, but it don't, so i have to use some strange constructions.